# How can I know when a new div is loading into my webapp

Tags: javascript, events, html

I am developing a webpage with different `div`s which are located in different files.
I have my `index.html` with several links. Every link is placing a different `div` from a file into the body of the main file. 
`OnLoad()` event happens only when the page first loads. 
My problem is that one `div` has a form with input fields. When I click on save, I open a confirmation page which is on another `div`. 
I need to put the values inside the fields before the user is clicking to save the details but I don't have any event that triggers in order to perform the initialization of the elements.

To simplify my problem:
I have `index.html` with a link. 
When clicking on the link it opens a `div` from a file named `form_div.html`.

`form_div.html` has a form with input fields and a continue button. 
When clicking on the continue button it opens another `div` from a file named `confirm_div.html`.

The values from `form_div.html` need to be set into the labels in `confirm_div.html`

At this step I am not aware about any event that happens in order for me to set the DOM elements with the values from the URL.

Note: I am NOT looking for something with JQuery.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a bespoke service where you tell the community what you want and we develop code for you. Demonstrate that you have at least made an effort by showing the code you've written so far and we'll help you sort out what's wrong.

Comment: He's not asking us to write his code for him.  He's asking how he can listen and react if his page is loaded with new content, which I think is a perfectly reasonble question.

Comment: It is, you're right.  The question isn't clear, but after re-reading it a few times I see that's what it's asking.  Could use a good edit.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are so adamant about not using some of the best tools for the job? What you are doing reads exactly like why we have jQuery and Ajax in the first place!

Comment: I'd say Derek Henderson's comment stands fit for this question. No code, no examples of WHAT has been tried already. Just a bunch of what is wanted and not wanted.

Comment: @daveL I agree that using modern tools is appropriate, but there are many reasons not to.  One excellent reason, of many, is if he's building a solution for a client, and the client demands that he don't add any extra libraries.  Maybe the client is wrong, but that's not up to the developer.  In the real world, it's not always so black-and-white.

Comment: @ChristopherW This question doesn't **need** any code or examples!  It's a very simple question.  He's described the scenario, and that's all we need to discuss his problem with him.

Comment: @JMTyler, The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), specifically the [appropriate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) section clearly identifies what type of questions are appropriate for this site, the keyword standing out is "specific". It's not a matter of discussion. If you would to discuss something with the OP, take it to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/). If the OP has an issue relating to software structure or best practice, go to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ChristopherW This is my last response because I don't think either of us care to keep going at this, but in my opinion, this question is plenty specific.  I understood what he was asking for (a way to attach to a *specific* event in JavaScript), and that seems pointed enough and communicated well enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is something like a kind of "rolling" on-load event, that will fire every time the DOM is injected with new content, I regret to tell you it doesn't exist.  If you're already listening to the `onclick` event of the links (in order to retrieve and inject the new div) then why can't you just do what you need to do there as well?